# Synonym of malicious, but more "competitive"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language

The word I am looking for is to describe an intentionally harmful duplicate. Sort of an evil twin, but in a competitive way - one who'd "test your might" in an actual tournament to give you a lesson rather than give you advice how to improve.

I like: **adversarious**, but it sounds too negative. **Customized** is too vague.

Comment: Look into the Inca myth of Piguerao and Apocatequil -twins, gods, and sometimes said to be one in the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "**evil or hostile doppelganger**"
Or 'adversarial'

doppelganger===something or someone that strongly resembles another

Comment: I thought about doppelganger and I'll roll with something similar. This is the only answer hitting on "duplication" element.

Answer (score 2):

How about nemesis?

Or adversary.

nemesis: the inescapable agent of someone's or something's downfall.
"the balance beam was the team's nemesis, as two gymnasts fell from the apparatus"

synonyms:   archrival, adversary, foe, opponent, arch enemy

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking about an [antagonist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Antagonist):

> 1. One who opposes and contends against another; an adversary.
> 2. The principal character in opposition to the protagonist or hero of a narrative or drama.

Comment: I might have not accented it properly, but the word I'm looking for should consider competition "pro-educational", and in that sense teaching a lesson. Antagonist, in my opinion, doesn't care if the protagonist learns anything.

Comment: Should that be a person or also something virtual?

Comment: I suppose either work: an agent or virtual force.

Answer (score 0):

I like 'viperous' (adj.)--having the qualities attributed to a viper; malignant; venomous. But a simpler alternative might be 'rival'--a versatile word which can be a noun, adjective or transitive verb (competing; striving to equal or surpass).